# How many questions do Blade Runners usually ask during a Voight-Kampff test?

Tags: blade-runner-series, blade-runner

In the original *Blade Runner* Deckard asks Rachel over a hundred questions before he confirms she's a replicant. However, Rachel is implied to be a special case. When administering the Voight-Kampff test, how many questions do Blade Runners normally ask before they're satisfied that someone being tested is human?

Answer (score 23):

**It typically requires 20 to 30 questions.**

From the script of *Blade Runner*:

> Deckard:  One more question. You're watching a stage play. A banquet is in progress. The guests are enjoying an appetizer of raw oysters. The entree consists of boiled dog.
> Tyrell:   Would you step out for a few moments, Rachael -- Thank you.
> Deckard:   She's a replicant, isn't she?
> Tyrell:    I'm impressed. How many questions does it usually take to spot them?
> Deckard:   I don't get it Tyrell.
> **Tyrell:  How many questions?
>
> Deckard:   Twenty, thirty, cross-referenced.**
> Tyrell:    It took more than a hundred for Rachael, didn't it?
> Deckard:   She doesn't know?!
> Tyrell:    She's beginning to suspect, I think.
> Deckard:   Suspect? How can it not know what it is?
> Tyrell:    Commerce, is our goal here at Tyrell. More human than human is our motto. Rachael is an experiment, nothing more. We began to recognize in them strange obsession. After all they are emotional inexperienced with only a few years in which to store up the experiences which you and I take for granted. If we gift them the past we create a cushion or pillow for their emotions and consequently we can control them better.
> Deckard:   Memories. You're talking about memories.

You can read [the complete script here...](https://www.trussel.com/bladerun.htm)

This dialogue also actually appears in the finished film. Watch it here

The line is spoken at around 1 minutes 20 seconds into the clip.

Comment: The real question is: how come it took only one question for Leon.

Comment: @Clockwork - I'm guessing he's especially unstable

Comment: @Clockwork You're assuming Leon ever intended to sit through the whole test.

Comment: @Graham Nah, the Blade Runner realised he was a replicant right away and the machine started beeping. Even for the second question, it beeped right away, which I assume means he's a replicant like in the game (although it didn't beep for Rachael).

Comment: @Clockwork I don't think the beeps mean anything but ambience. My guess is that Leon was particularly violent and not very bright, and got disturbed and reacted with violence.